# I'm getting this while developing a React Website of E-Commerce

Tags: reactjs

(anonymous function)
F:/Udit/React Project/E-Commerce/e_commerce/src/Component/CheckoutForm/AddressForm.jsx:26

24 |  }

25 |  useEffect(() => {

> 26 |    fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
> | ^  27 |  }, []);
> 28 |
> 29 |  return (

- Compiled Version -----

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1009:42
1006 | };
1007 |
1008 | Object(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["useEffect"])(() => {

> 1009 |   fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
> |                                        ^  1010 | }, []);
> 1011 | return /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["jsxDEV"])